# Supporting arbitrary hostnames on Windows Azure Web Apps

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Windows Azure Web Apps let subscription administrators define custom hostnames for a web-app, these have to be manually listed, but you can also specify wildcard hostnames for subdomains, e.g. `*.myapp.com`.

So if I have a multi-tenant application where each tenant has their own vanity hostname, they could be "billselectrical.myapp.com" and "megabusiness.myapp.com" - and hostname detection in my application code would handle the rest.

However, is it possible to have arbitrary hostnames in Azure Web Apps? What if my (high-profile) customer megabusiness.com wants my hosted-application to appear as "myapp.megabusiness.com"? Obviously I can support this by explicitly and manually adding myapp.megabusiness.com to the Azure domain list (which does require adding verification TXT records, unfortunately - so this requires cooperation from the customer) - but there doesn't seem to be a way to instruct Windows Azure to allow any hostname.

...or is there?

I note that I know this is achievable using a raw VM with a manually configured IIS website - I imagine the same is possible with a Web Role Worker too.

Comment: Per my understanding, you have already known that you could specify wildcard custom domain of your root domain or the sub-domain of the root domain from your customer, in order to map various domains to your Azure Web App. As I know, mapping a custom domain to site hosted on Azure or raw VM, you could log in to your domain registrar’s management site to create the DNS record(s) or migrating the domain DNS Server to Azure and creating DNS record(s) on Azure Portal.

Comment: Does that mean you could configure any custom domains on Azure without the cooperation from your customers? Please provide more detailed requirement, then we could better help you.

Comment: @Bruce-MSFT Correct, I'd like to be able to configure an Azure Website with a *completely* wildcard host-header binding (not just subdomain-wildcard) and also to not have to set-up TXT/CNAME validation records for Windows Azure either.

Comment: You can only register a wildcard domain for a domain that you've proved the ownership for. In regular IIS you can of course have a web app mapped to *, but not in Web Apps. In Azure you inherently share some infrastructure like IP addresses, so it has to be able to know exactly where a request should go based on the Host header. If multiple apps had such a wildcard under the same address, where should the request go?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem? I’m currently facing the same issue